# instance of generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I want to write a little "factory" for a number of methods that has the same set of arguments. Here is my code so far (it is so wrong that event the IDE won't let it it pass)

```
 public <T> T callServer(String param1, String param2, String param3){
    if (T instanceof Type1 ){
        return (T) callFunctionServerType1(param1,  param2, param3);
    }
    else if (T instanceof Type2)
        return  (T) callFunctionServerType2(param1,  param2, param3);
    return null;
}
```

The IDE says that and ***expression is expected*** and underlines each T thas is just after the if statement (if (T ...) ). Can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: On line 2, `T` is not an instance. Replace T with something that *is* an instance of an object in order to get your code to compile. Furthermore, due to type erasure, you should understand that without an actual instance around, you won't be able to detect what `T` is at runtime anyway.

Comment: T is generic type parameter and can't be an instance of anything. Try to pass additional Class<?> parameter and check that parameter on instance of.

Comment: This also looks like a really bad idea design-wise, but the IDE won't even warn you about that.

Comment: @Kayaman, please can you go into details why it is a bad idea.

Comment: This really isn't how Java is intended to be used.  You're really, really intended to use different method names, not an overload.

Comment: @Kayaman - it is not a bad idea and it is in almost every frameworks, because there is no other way when generic return type defined on method level. There is a way to get a class of T when it is defined on Class level.

Comment: @Vadim No, don't claim that every framework uses this construct. You don't even understand what's wrong with the piece of code. See Louis Wasserman's comment.

Comment: There is nothing to talk about... Did you ever work with Webservices, XML, JAXB? I do not care about "academic theories"... Such things are in use in Hibernate, Spring, Apache CXF, Apache Commons, JAXB(JAXWS in JDK) and so on...

Comment: @Vadim There's nothing academic about this. Your "solution" is equivalent to passing a `String` to a method and then doing a switch on it to see what function will really be called. You've most likely misunderstood what a `Class` parameter is useful for, and your claims about this abuse of design being used in those frameworks is completely unfounded. Of course if you'd like to provide examples of where those frameworks use this particular construct, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: I have more important things to do rather than that... I saw it and it is enough for me.

Comment: Please guys get off your high horses and teach me why it is wrong as a design (not sarcastic, I'm learning). I'm using it on Android with Retrofit2. The thing with Retrofit 2 is that you have to know in advance the type of return of each server call you make (when using a gson factory). All I want is to have one centralized method that I call and it chooses the right call. Now please explain to me why @Vadim 's answer is wrong and what is wrong with my the piece of code.

Comment: It's hard to provide proper design based on such a small code snippet. However having to know the return value in advance isn't exactly special. Java is a strongly typed language, so you always need to know in advance (at least to some degree) what kind of types you're working with. This kind of code is a workaround for bad design, it's a better idea to fix the underlying problem rather than the symptoms. Show some example usage of your code, it's impossible to determine what you're doing from what you're showing.

Comment: Your code logically correct (aside of "good or bad design"), but instanceof applicable to the Object not to the Class. Any Class is always instance of Class nothing else. And more: there is no way to get actual Class behind generic type T declared on method level at run time. If you'd like stay with that design there is only one way... but if you care about "proper design" you will have more complex code, more classes/interfaces etc... It is up to you...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass needed class of T as additional parameter

```
public <T> T callServer(String param1, String param2, String param3, Class<? extends T> returnClass)
{
  if (Type1.class.isAssignableFrom(returnClass)) {
     ...
```

Comment: Real live example: there are 50 webservices with about 1000 types (i.e. objects) in each. It is needed to have utility class to unmarshal each of them from XML to the corresponding Java object ... so your and Wasserman's suggestion to have 50,000 methods? OK... no problem, but... in every release some types changes and some new types come... then - with every small change your utility with 50,000 methods must be updated and redeployed... very-very good "academic theoretical" design... While only one method with no more that 10 lines of code needs forever...

Comment: That's absolute bullcrap. You'd use code generation and/or reflection in that case, not manually edit some `callServer()` method. Your "one method with 10 lines" can handle 50 webservices and 1000 types? Those must be some long lines.

Comment: You did not get a question, so ... It is not a place to discuss that. make a separate question and I maybe answer... good luck.

Comment: I'm not looking for answers. I'm trying to make you understand that you're offering bad advice, and maybe even writing bad code yourself. There's nothing academic about this, and I've worked with webservices and XML and JAXB etc. for years. Please don't answer questions when you only *think* you know the answer. Some people may think you are speaking from experience instead of misconceptions.

Comment: @Kayaman please can you write a pseudo code and explain to me what I'm suppose to do instead. The use-case that Vadim is talking about is exactly what I'm trying to work around (yet I'm using json not xml).

Comment: It does not matter json, xml or anything else. Conclusion is about - is it good to have a logic based on actual Class of generic return type T inside the method or do it outside. @Kayman point: it is bad idea. (with no explanation why) just bad - period. My point: it is not bad for all cases and sometime useful, reduce code size, eliminate code duplication and makes code more reusable overtime.

Comment: @Vadim so far your solution suits me very well. It works and it understands the purpose behind. I'd rather edit one file than have to go to through so many more (with time). I'm waiting for the alternative (which is not yet provided). Thank you very much Vadim

Comment: I don't know if it's because of the poor example code provided, but I still fail to see how it "reduces code size, eliminates code duplication or makes code reusable" when a new `callFunctionServerType3` method is added and you need to edit an *extra* place in code. It certainly sounds like it will only **add** to the code size.

Comment: Another design please... and how it will look like when another callFunctionServerType3 will be added.  purpose of provided code is clear BTW